# API cursor pagination jump to specific page

Tags: pagination

I'm looking into implementing cursor pagination in a project API that I'm building.  I've got it setup so that the url contains `/?cursor=<the next id>` (EX: `/?cursor=60` starts at ID 61).  I've noticed that a lot of implementations will base64_encode the cursor value.  I believe this is because it allows you to add more info the cursor (other filters, etc.).  Once this encoding happens, it seems like you lose the ability to jump to a certain page, like you could with offset pagination or by not encoding the cursor.

Is this true?  Is there something I'm missing to enable jumping to a certain page with cursor pagination using an encoded cursor?